# Is reading pirated books a sin?

Tags: karma, dharma, sin

I am a mathematics student and it is not economically feasible for me to buy every book that I need for my studies. Even reading a specific topic sometimes requires 2-3 different books. So like most people around me, I too download the books from various websites like libgen, bookfi, etc.

Is reading or downloading books that I have not purchased myself a sin according to Hindu scripture?

Comment: Use archive.org to read any books

Comment: Not sure of what scriptures say but I think it depends on way you are thinking. For example, if you are thinking of intentionally doing bad to anyone making him suffer then of course it is a sin but if you don't want others to suffer and bcoz of financial problems do such things then it should not be a sin..its actually the vibes we are generating that decides whether it is a sin or not. However, I would still suggest that if you are capable enough then you should pay the price and then   enjoy the things.

Comment: Also, try to place yourself in the other person's shoes and then think if the same happens to you when you are a publisher and somebody takes a pirated copy what will you do. Whether you will ignore or curse the other person, what mental tensions, etc you will be going through at that time... if nobody suffers then according to me it's not a sin but if somebody is suffering then you are producing bad karma for yourself and then be ready to repent the same.

Comment: One more thought, if you are getting a pirated copy bcoz of your financial problems then atleast donot distribute if further in public, such that it would altogether make losses to the publisher. If nobody or only a few people will purchase the books then the publisher will definately be in losses and you will be responsible for the same. You can however decide to distribute to some really needy people as that would really be a help.

Comment: @Aby nicely said. Just to add, OP can visit his/her library of school/college/university. Libraries are meant for this purpose. But breach of copyright is not advisable. It is a "Chaurya Karma" (theft).

Comment: You answered your question already. "illegally" downloaded books. What else are you looking for? Do you think Hinduism supports theft or illegality?

Comment: @Aby Do not use comments for giving advises. You can use answer section when the question is open.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, Aby may not be having scrip reference, so he might have posted a comment instead of an answer. This is my guess. He can clarify it of course.

Comment: @Vineet Comments are not for answering. Comments are not for answers without sources. They should be only used for asking clarifications (for questions) and suggesting improvements (for answers). Purpose of closing questions is not served if answers are written in comments.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, I knew if I write the same comments in an answer,then they will be marked as comments as they donot have scriptural reference, so until I find some examples in scripts to support my comments till that time I posted that as a comment. I 'll try to find some examples and post them together as answer

Comment: @Aby That is not an excuse. Don't use comments as an answer. As I said already, they are not for writing unsourced answers. They don't help the site in anyway. We are not here to help only the OP. We need not to add scriptures every time. Not everyone is an expert in it. You can use any source in the faq to back it up.

Comment: I am in the same position. I love mathematics, but I can't purchase all the books I read! So I also visit websites like libgen.